# handling multiple query parameters in tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

How can I handle parameters like in `www.www.ww/api/user=XXX&comment=XXX&friend=XXX` style queries(multiple parameters), couldn't found in documentation. (maybe didn't read well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used tasypi, but you can access the get parameters in django from an `HttpRequest` object (normally within a view) like so -

```
if 'user' in request.GET:
    user = request.GET['user']
```

Have a look a the [django docs on request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/). You might even find it handy to check the docs on [writing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/). A basic view (as apposed to a class based view) uses the HttpRequest as an argument to the function. So

```
def my_view(request):
    if 'user' in request.GET:
        user = request.GET['user']
    if 'comment' in request.GET:
        comment = request.GET['comment']
```

EDIT

A glance at the [Tastypi docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering) suggests that you should be using the `class Meta` on your Resource to set this up. Something like -

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        filtering = {
            "user": ('exact',),
            "friend": ('exact',),
            "comment": ('exact',)
        }
```

I believe you can also get at the GET parameters through `bundle.request.GET` if that's any use.